# Html Textarea Placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, input, textarea

I have a textarea which when in focus should empty the text holder and when out of focus should get back the original text or retain any text that was written while in focus.

**EDIT:**

i know how to select the text area.
$("textarea").text();

i am not sure how to clear the content when u click on the textarea to nothing and then again get back the content when out of focus.

Comment: So you have two elements - 'textarea' and 'textholder'.  'textarea' should take and store the contents of 'textholder' when it gets focus, and give this same text back to 'textholder' when it loses focus?

Comment: So what's your actual question? Where lies your problem?

Comment: @guys sorry my native lang is not English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you're trying to do the thing where you get instructions in the textarea and then if you delete the value you get the instructions again. Try this

```
<textarea id="a">Message</textarea>

var standard_message = $('#a').val();
$('#a').focus(
    function() {
        if ($(this).val() == standard_message)
            $(this).val("");
    }
);
$('#a').blur(
    function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
            $(this).val(standard_message);
    }
);
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tywvh).

Comment: thanks a lot. exactly what i was looking for. i was trying to understrand which function to use .focus and .blur thank cambraca

Comment: For a more feature complete polyfill/shim of the native `placeholder` attribute, check out this great project: http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/.

Answer (score 15):

Just add [the `placeholder` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-placeholder):

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="input placeholder" />
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="textarea placeholder"></textarea>
```

Comment: placeholder is an HTML5 attribute and does not work in IE7 or IE8.  Be advised that unless you have a label or use a javascript-based solution your form will be broken in the previously mentioned browsers.

Comment: @siliconrockstar - It won't work in IE9 either. However, there are numerous [`placeholder` attribute polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) available that will add support to older browsers. This solution is semantically better.

Comment: @ JA - Thanks for the link to your javascript-based solution.